# How can I change the name of my x value in r plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have the plot:

```
 plot(Combined$TIMESTAMP,                              # Draw first time series
 Combined$GPP_NT_VUT_REF,
 type = "l",
 col = 2,
 ylim = c(0, 15),
 xlab = "",
 ylab = expression(paste("GPP [gC m"^"-2 "," day "^"-1]"))) +


 lines(Combined$TIMESTAMP,                             # Draw second time series
  Combined$GPP_WRF_mean,
  type = "l",
  col = 3) +

  legend("topright",                           # Add legend to plot
   c("OBS", "WRF"),
   lty = 1,
   col = 2:4)
```

which produces the timeseries graph with the name of x values equal to gen, feb, mar and I want to convert my x values in J,F,M,A,M,J...

I tried with:

```
 axis(1, at=1:12, labels=month.name, cex.axis=0.5)
```

but it doesn't work - any help?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the first letter of `month.name` or from `month.abb`:

```
month.1st.letter <- sub("(^[[:upper:]]).*$", "\\1", month.abb)
```

Then use this vector as the `labels` argument.

```
axis(1, at = 1:12, labels = month.1st.letter, cex.axis = 0.5)
```

---

### Edit

Start by removing the plus signs from the code, base R graphics do not add up. Then, in the `plot` instruction include `xaxt = "n"`. And plot the axis right after it.

```
plot(Combined$TIMESTAMP,                              # Draw first time series
 Combined$GPP_NT_VUT_REF,
 type = "l",
 col = 2,
 ylim = c(0, 15),
 xaxt = "n",        # here, no x axis
 xlab = "",
 ylab = expression(paste("GPP [gC m"^"-2 "," day "^"-1]")))
axis(1, at = 1:12, labels = month.1st.letter, cex.axis = 0.5)
```

Comment: I don't understand where I have to use the this command: axis(1, at = 1:12, labels = month.1st.letter, cex.axis = 0.5) after the last plus sign??

Comment: @Beatrice See if the edit solves it. And remove **all** plus signs from the code.

Comment: But in this way I eliminate the second line of my plot...

Comment: I've tried but doesn't work

Comment: @Beatrice In base graphics you must run the instructions one by one. After the code in my answer, run the rest of your code, the `lines` and the `legend` instructions.

Comment: Yes I understad but doesn't work anyway. After I discoverd, in another website, that this is a R bug.

Comment: @Beatrice Can you post the output of `dput(Combined)`. I am not understanding what doesn't work and I doubt that there is a bug in a very used and tested base R function, there must be something else going on that we can solve if the code can be run with data. Can you also post a link to that other website?